# Generating eroded mountain terrain in a local / 'bottom-up' way

Tags: math, dimension, terrain, fractals, procedural-generation

I'm picturing a typical random polygon hillside with ridges that come together into bigger ridges as you ascend and canyons that come together into bigger canyons as you descend.

The way you normally make something like this is to start with the top of the whole mountain and iterate until you have enough detail in the area you're interested in and then stop.

OK, suppose there is no absolute mountain top; it just keeps going; and I want to generate the neighboring chunk before I get to it so it matches up with what is already there.

After thinking about it for a while I think this is probably either impossible or involves a kind of math I haven't even heard of. On the other hand it -seems- like it 'should' be possible, (with extra information stored per-vertex)?

Comment: The scenario you describe sounds a little bit like a random walk: from where you are, you wander off in one direction or another. I guess you will need a 2-dimensional random walk. I believe such things have been investigated for generating artificial topography. I don't have any references, but perhaps a web search will turn up something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try doing it in 2D first and see what you can come up with.
It looks possible in 2D, in 3d it would work too but not with a real mountain with a top, more with an endless slope that does not converge to a point.
What you want to do is actually reversing the gravity rules in some sense.
Not sure if this is really an answer, but the question is quite vague too :)